# jackson json schema, possible values without using an 'enum' class

Tags: json, enums, annotations, schema, jackson

Jackson json schema automatically detects enum type classes and adds a list of possible values in the schema - For eg

```
{"type":"object","properties":{"myfield":{"type":"string","enum":["val1","val2"]}}}
```

Is it possible to annotate non enum fields so that they can also take a closed set of values??

Comment: basically is there any possible annotations that helps me add 'possible values' for a field in jackson json schema?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Serialize Json into generic structure without schema using Java and Jackson](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837604/serialize-json-into-generic-structure-without-schema-using-java-and-jackson)