# Jackson deserialize JSON Arrays of JSON Objects in deeply nested JSON as a String

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to deserialize JSON String using:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
MappingIterator<Object> mappingIt = ObjectMapper.reader(Map.class).readValues(jsonString)
while (mappingIterator.hasNext()) {
                String next = mapper.writeValueAsString(mappingIterator.next());
                result.add(next);
}
```

but I got from:

```
{"xxx":"xx xx", "xx":"xx","xx":[{"x":"x"},{"x":"x"}]}
```

JSON Array as a String:

```
{"xxx":"xx xx", "xx":"xx","xx":"[{\"x\":\"x\"},{\"x\":\"x\"}]"}
```

How to avoid getting JSON Arrays as a String?
I'm using Jackson.

Comment: How's `Map.class` defined or is it the default one from Java standard library? Please update your question with an MCVE.

Comment: It's from standard Java library.

Comment: Right. Did you try with your own custom class defined exactly according to the given JSON?

Comment: As far as it should deserialize all JSON objects I haven't defined POJO for this purpose. The object I have provided is just a part of a deeply nested JSON.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Serialize Json into generic structure without schema using Java and Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35837604/serialize-json-into-generic-structure-without-schema-using-java-and-jackson)

Comment: It works partially (many thanks, @Simon Kocurek!) namely the JSON Array is no longer a String, however I'm getting bellow:

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.MappingIterator

Anyone can help how to map it properly?

Comment: Trying not to use MappingIterator (using instead Map<String, Object>) makes JSON Array a String (as at the beggining).